# OpenMP depend clause - rule on structure elements

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm struggling to understand the rules in the 5.2 specifications regarding what is allowed in an OpenMP depend clause with respect to types in Fortran.

The basic code I'm testing is this clause (as a proxy for a larger example):

`!$omp task private(jj, i) firstprivate(j, jj_end) shared(e12c) depend(out: e12c%e12f%e12t)`

`e12c%e12f%e12t` is a type containing a type containing an array.

Page 62 of the spec says:

> Unless otherwise specified, a variable that is part of another variable (as an array element or a
> structure element) cannot be a variable list item, an extended list item or locator list item.

I know that array elements are allowed as members of a depend clause (and the code works with both gfortran12 and ifort if its only `e12c%e12t` without the extra type in between), and I think I'd assumed structure members were as well (and at least for non-nested structure members this works).

If I try this code with gfortran 12 then it fails to compile, however with intel 2023.0.0 it compiles ok. Is it valid OpenMP code or do I need to find another way (is there another way?) to express such dependencies?
Notably the C equivalent (`depend(out: e12c.e12f.e12t[j:j+32])`) compiles ok with gcc12, so is this just gfortran lagging behind again?

Adressing the comment, the gfortran compiler just says a syntax error:

```
gfortran -fopenmp test.f90
test.f90:26:82:

   26 |   !$omp task private(jj, i) firstprivate(j, jj_end) shared(e12c) depend(out: e12c%e12f%e12t)
      |                                                                                  1
Error: Syntax error in OpenMP variable list at (1)
```

For Ian's comment, to be explicit as to what everything is, here is the full Fortran file that fails with gcc:

```
module ax
    implicit none
type array_container
    real, dimension(500, 500) ::e12t
end type

type array_container2
    type(array_container) :: e12f
end type

end module ax

Program test
use ax
type(array_container2) :: e12c
integer, dimension(500,500):: dum
integer :: i, ii, j, jj, jj_end

e12c%e12f%e12t(:,:) = 1.0

!$omp parallel default(shared) private(j, jj_end)
!$omp single
DO j = 1, 500, 32
  jj_end =  MIN(j_out_var + (32 - 1), 500)

  !$omp task private(jj, i) firstprivate(j, jj_end) shared(e12c) depend(out: e12c%e12f%e12t)
  Do jj = j, jj_end, 1
    Do i = 1, 500, 1
      e12c%e12f%e12t(i,j) = 1.0
    End Do
  End Do
  !$omp end task
End Do
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel

End Program
```

Comment: Added to original comment

Comment: Intel compiler on a real example gives a more sensible response:
`Only array fields within a record may be specified in a DEPEND clause of a !$OMP TASK directive.`

This probably answers the question, but I can't replicate it in a standalone example.

Comment: This is still a strange message because a "record" is not a Fortran term nor a term from the OpenMP specification. But the message writers are not always exact.

Comment: It would help us if you showed exactly what `e12c%e12f%e12t` is.

Comment: Edited to add the full testcase - you can change `e12t` to be a non-array field as well to see if you can replicate the issue with Intel, but I was not able to. The major example I could share links to repos but its quite an investment to setup relatively, this case should work for now.

Comment: My current guess is that the OpenMP standard is happy with it if its an array section/member and not otherwise probably.